# Mongodb installation having some problem with version 4.0.2

Tags: mongodb

After I installed mongodb, I tried entering `mongod` and got this message:

[image]

Can anyone help on resolving this issue?

Comment: Please do not embed messages as screenshot, but as code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build an empty directory on **C:/data/db**

Answer (score 0):

Just create data folder C:\data\db or start your mongod process (or update C/your_install_directory>/bin/mongod.cfg) to change data folder used by mongod process. (don't forget to create this folder)